# Placing a cookie on visitors Computer to my bloggspot/blogger website

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

I run a blog (in blogger/blogspot). I need help placing a cookie on a visitors computer. Also I need help on placing information on that certain cookie. To be more exact of what I want to do.
When a visitor clicks an external link (api.viglink) a cookie is placed with some info in it. How can I place my own cookie with the info that I want in it??
Please be descriptive with your solutions. Not just code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to run JavaScript:

```
function setcookie(name, value, exp) {
var today = new Date();
var expires = new Date();
var ndays = 1;
var path = '/';
var domain = 'yourdomain.blogger.com';
var secure = false;
var val = escape(value) || "";
exp = (exp == -1) ? true : false;
if (exp) {
    expires.setDate(today.getDate() - 1)
} else {
    if (ndays == null || ndays == 0) ndays = 1;
    expires.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * ndays)
};
document.cookie = name + "=" + val + ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") + ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") + ((secure) ? "; secure" : "")
}
```

Comment: So you just attach an event on that link (onclick="functionName()"), and when it is clicked, use setcookie function, given it: cookie name, the value to store, and days after which it should expire

Comment: no no, I think I wasn't precise enough (my english is not that good). When a visitor clicks a certain link a cookie is placed on his browser. I wish to place the exact same cookie but without the need for the visitor to click on that link

Comment: Uhm.. well.. you follow the same logic using the information you have in the answers. On page load, I suppose? if you have the cookie contents, just use setcookie, if you don't have cookie contents and there's no way to get it dynamically, well, nothing can help here. :)

Comment: yes, document.cookie provide you with all cookies set to browser for the current website, all you have to do is split the string, find your cookie and get the contents.. take a look on getcookie function in W3Cschools, or use jQuery+jcookie plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
    expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Copied from [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: and how do I add the info I want it to have??

Answer (score 0):

You pass the values you have into the variables of the function. Remember that the only required information needed to create a cookie is the name/value pair.

Something like:

```
document.cookie = "name=value;" + "expires=Sat, 16 May 2009 18:40:22 GMT";[1]
```

This is also how you can set a cookie. I hope I am answering your questions.

Steve

[1] http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/set-cookie/